# MySQL Update Statement + File Upload

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Been staring at this all day and can't seem to figure out why my update statement fails to update the field 'image_filename':

```
 $fileName = $_FILES['image_filename'];

 if($fileName["name"] <> ""){
      $imageFile = $fileName['name']; 
      $destination = "../../../../assets/resources/images/".$fileName['name'];
      move_uploaded_file($fileName['name'], $destination);
 } 

 $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE content SET image_filename='$imageFile' WHERE id=%s",
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['resource_id'], "int"));

 mysql_select_db($database_conn_talent, $conn_talent);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $conn_talent) or die(mysql_error());
```

Can a SQL pro tell me what I"m missing?  Much thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: I"m sorry to sound dense but I didn't realize I needed to accept answers that have been provided.  Not sure how I missed that aspect.  Will accept them now.  thanks.

Comment: @Jason: it's fairly recent and appears on your profile. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=accept+rate

Comment: Thanks GBN.  Didn't notice that subtle check mark next to the answers.  Found it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be building a query, but never executing it. Also, Drupal'll handle all the `sprintf`ing for you, if you let it.

```
$query = "UPDATE content SET image_filename='$imageFile' WHERE id=%i";
db_query($query, $_POST['resource_id']);
```

Comment: My bad.  I didn't paste that part of my code (updated now).  Thanks!

Comment: If this is in Drupal, why are you rolling your own database connections? Drupal handles all that for you, what you're doing is redundant.

Comment: Hi. Its not Drupal.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm going to remove the Drupal tag from your question, then. Why did you include it?